# Implement a voltage feedback method to reduce the crosstalkin resistive matrix

Tags: feedback, matrix, crosstalk, resistive

I'm new in electronics and i want to develop a resistive matrix that is pressure sensitive. Right now, I have a 7x7 matrix and I'm implementing this using multiplexers, a reference resistor and an Arduino. The Figure below demonstrates what I have done by using pressure sensitive cells.

[image]

This solution is working fine but now, I want to implement a Voltage Feedback Circuit (VFC) to reduce the crosstalk between the pressure sensitive cells. Basically, VFC consists of applying to the unselected cells, the feedback voltage in order to get voltage drops of 0. And this needs to be done dinamically because the row and column that it is being written is also changing. In order to implement this, do I need to add more multiplexers? The figure below represents what I want to implement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put diodes in series with each resistor like this: -

[image]

Now, there can be no cross-talk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As my matrix is a flexible one, I don't want to add diodes to it.

Comment: Well, your proposal doesn't look like it will work so, you either plod on trying to make it work until you abandon the idea and live with the cross-talk or fit diodes.